# Regarding memory and variable assignment in PHP

Tags: php, variables, memory, variable-assignment

Ive asked a similar question before but i was really unclear so ive decided to use a more concrete example.

Does php save the result of the variable or does it save the procedure to run it? Why im wondering is if i store a function in it, does it store the return value or just copies the procedure

say:

```
    function foo($something)
{

    for loop
        {
       echo 'Something';

       }

   return $something;
}


$b = foo(5);
```

from what i encountered just assigning the value executes the function. Which i dont want because i dont want to go through double the for loops and do double what could be inside.

Comment: `i dont want to go through double the for loops and do double what could be inside.` -- could you explain?

Comment: You are not "storing a function in it" when you run this line: "$b = foo(5);" -- you are running a function called foo with an argument of 5, and storing the returned value in a variable called $b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can have both (either store result, or function's code)

if you write:

```
function foo()
{
    return 5;
}
$a = foo();
```

this will mean - execute function foo and store result into $a

if you write:

```
$a = function()
{
    return 5;
};
$a();
```

this will mean - store function's code into variable $a, then execute function stored in $a

Comment: what if the function is stored in a object? Like i want to make $a = object->function  but not execute it right away.

Comment: You can store even function name in variable and call it via call_user_func(array($obj, 'functioname'), $a), check out more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a [strict programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_programming_language), meaning that expressions are always completely evaluated. The line

```
$b = foo(5);
```

computes the value for `foo(5)` before the assignment; PHP does not leave it as a [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29) to be evaluated when or if the variable `$b` is used.

If you want to you can achieve something similar to a thunk by creating a closure, like this:

```
$b = function() { return foo(5); };
```

This will not evaluate `foo(5)` until its value is needed, and then to get the value you must call the closure as `$b()`.